# List property inheritance

Tags: dart

The parser is complaining that the property inheritor .list is not subtype of ModelList.list, but LeadsGroup does inherit from Model.
Is this wrong? What is the correct way to do this?

My base class:

```
abstract class ModelList {
    List<Model> get list;
    set list(List<Model> n);
}
```

The inheritor:

```
class ListLeadsGroup extends ModelList {
    List<LeadsGroup> list;
}

class LeadsGroup extends Model {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution using the new keyword `covariant`. Now the classes that extends ModelList can override the `List<Model>` list without warnings.

```
@serializable
abstract class ModelList extends ModifiedModel
        implements Model {
    Type get listType {
        throw new UnimplementedError();
    }

    List<Model> get list;
    set list(covariant List n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have code like

```
class Foo extends ModelList {}

ModelList ml = new ListLeadsGroup();
ml.list.add(new Foo());
```

`ml.list` is of type `Model`, therefore adding `Foo` should be legit.
But this very likely is not what you want.
This is why `List<ListLeadsGroup>` can't override `List<Model>`.

This should do what you want:

```
abstract class ModelList<T extends Model> {
    List<T> get list;
    set list(List<T> n);
}

class ListLeadsGroup extends ModelList<LeadsGroup> {
    List<LeadsGroup> list;
}

class LeadsGroup extends Model {
}
```

just copied from Matan Lurey's comment on Gitter

> ```
> import 'package:func/func.dart';
>
> class ModelRegistry {
>   final _factories = <Type, Func0<Model>>{};
>
>   Model create(Type type) => _factories[type]();
>
>   void register(Type type, Model factory()) {
>     _factories[type] = factory;
>   }
> }
>
> main() {
>   var registry = new ModelRegistry();
>   registry.register(FooModel, () => new FooModel());
>   var foo = registry.create(FooModel);
> }
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem with that is that I can't use reflectable to generate a dynamic instance of ModelList neither find the runtimeType of T

Comment: Hi Gunter, would I be able to use reflectable and this? I think that this kind of logic would lead me to create another reflectable system in the long run

Comment: Not sure what you want to do with reflectable. Using reflection is also discouraged for browser applications and not supported at all in Flutter.

Comment: my application shares models (the same class) between the browser application and the server. The idea is to receive json from the server and translate it to an object that would be attached to forms with ngModel etc. The server also expects most of posts to be translated to objects to be used within the controllers. Maybe in the future I change this to a transformer or something more hard coded, however, reflection gives me production time for now

Comment: I'd just create a registry of factory methods.

Comment: do you have examples please?

Comment: Something like final `myFactories = <String,Function>{'MyClass1': () => new MyClass1(), 'MyClass2': () => new MyClass2(), }`. I guess it also works without the quotes like `myFactories = <Type,Function>{MyClass1: () => new MyClass1(), MyClass2: () => new MyClass2(), }`

Comment: Gunter, how would you work with a json rest api? with decoded maps or with the decoded objects from the json?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. What's the problem?

Comment: you say that I shouldn't use reflection, since I would not be able to use it within Flutter for example. However, my apps are all based on REST API interfaces that spits a JSON. My question is, how would you work the data got from the API, with the raw JSON or by decoding it into it's source class?

Comment: Generate classes that match the JSON structure. For example https://medium.com/dartlang/darts-built-value-for-serialization-f5db9d0f4159 manually or using https://github.com/dart-lang/build and https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen

Comment: Or one of the other JSON serialization packages.